# Display dialog causing error

Tags: dialog, applescript

I have a simple dialog. The user can either accept the dialog or cancel it. But when I cancel, it errors. Why?

```
try
    display dialog "I cause an error when my 'cancel' button is pressed."
on error error_message number error_number
    display dialog "Error: " & error_number & ":" & error_message & "."
end try
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one that doesn't error!

```
display dialog "I won't cause an error because I specified the buttons myself and didn't include a cancel button!" buttons {"Quit", "OK"} default button 2
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Cancel` button always causes an error in the `display dialog` command. You cannot fix that. However, if you do as @regulus6633 suggested and specify the buttons yourself, you won't have to worry about errors.